# Can developer verify a Test Plan document?

Tags: testing, review, test-plan

I have created test plan document. We have a small team of developers and testers. Should I involve developers in verifying a test plan document?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is fine for a developer to verify the test-plan.

The danger is that the tester begins to rely on the developer's comments. If that happens your tests may not do any more than what the developer has already tested.

If you can ensure this doesn't happen there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you email sent out with document reviewal ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Project Manager or Developer Team Lead can be involved for reviewing Test Plan. It depends on organization.